# generic parameter to function c#

Tags: c#, generics

Good day!
Can't understand why do compiler highline it as error. Could somebody tell me "why". What do I wrong?
So, I have one generic class

```
    public abstract class SimpleElement<TDataIndexer> where TDataIndexer:IDataIndexator 
{
    public TDataIndexr[] po_registr;
    protected Update updateDelegate;
}
```

Also, I have delegate, which dealing with updating visual component

```
public delegate object Update(IDataIndexator[] regs);
```

My delegate requires parameter type `IDataIndexer`. How I can pass generic parameter to that delegate?

```
public delegate object Update(IDataIndexator[] regs);
public abstract class SimpleElement<TDataIndexer> where TDataIndexer:IDataIndexator 
    {
        public TDataIndexr[] po_registr;
        protected Update updateDelegate;
        public function foo(){
            this.updateDelegate(po_registr); // here is error that parameter should be IDataIndexator[], but not TDataIndexer[]
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: TDataIndexer can't be transformed to IDataIndexator.

Comment: You need to add as `class` constraint for `TDataIndexer` - `where TDataIndexer : class, IDataIndexer`. Be aware that array covariance is unsafe, so you could still see exceptions.

Comment: @Lee, can you explain more about the usage of `class` in this context? Or can you provide some documentation? Thanks

Comment: @bruno.almeida - C# arrays are covariant, so a `TDataIndexer[]` is compatible with `IDataIndexer[]` when `TDataIndexer` is a reference type. See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity/) for an explanation of why C# variance is not compatible with value types. Array covariance is considered a mistake, see [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2013/06/22/array-covariance-not-just-ugly-but-slow-too/) for an explanation.

Comment: @Lee, great documentation. Wasn't aware of the **representation-changing conversions** problems. That explains the need of `class`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for what you think *should* happen automatically to work, your `TDataIndexer` must be constrained to a `class`

```
public abstract class SimpleElement<TDataIndexer> 
    where TDataIndexer:class, IDataIndexator 
{ ...}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/KDI86395

Comment: Well, i think this is the correct answer. Can you explain please? Thanks.

Comment: I also wonder _why_ this solves it. Probably because the compiler doesn't know if it has to box the values or not (`IDataIndexator` could be implemented by a struct), but I thought it would emit code for both ways. btw: constraining to `struct` does not work...

Answer (score 1):

Try use .Cast

```
public interface IDataIndexator { }

public delegate object Update(IDataIndexator[] regs);
public abstract class SimpleElement<TDataIndexer> where TDataIndexer : IDataIndexator
{
    public TDataIndexer[] po_registr;
    protected Update updateDelegate;
    public void foo()
    {
        this.updateDelegate(po_registr.Cast<IDataIndexator>().ToArray()); // here is error that parameter should be IDataIndexator[], but not TDataIndexer[]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `TDataIndexr : IDataIndexator` doesn't mean that `TDataIndexr[]` is `IDataIndexator[]` in the eyes of the compiler.

Create `IDataIndexator[]` or do `this.updateDelegate(po_registr.Cast<IDataIndexator>().ToArray());`.

Basically in a way the system expects to get a parameter of type `Array<IDataIndexator>`, you are passing `Array<SomeType>`, where `typeof(SomeType) != typeof(IDataIndexator)`. Therefore for the compiler `typeof(Array<IDataIndexator>) != typeof(Array<SomeType>)` and error is produced.